# jQuery html() on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad

`var partnerId = $('.partnerId').html();`

The code above pulls the inner html from

`<span id="_ctl0_ContentPlaceHolder1_lPartnerID" class="partnerId">1122</span></td>`

correctly on IE7 and firefox. The code fails on iPad.

`alert(partnerId)` returns "1122" correctly on FireFox and IE7.  But, on iPad I get

`<a href="tel:1122">1122</a>` as my return value.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a moment before I posted, I figured out how to fix the problem.  Someone else may benefit from this solution so I posted anyhow.  The issue is due to iPads telephone number detection.  iPad wraps what it believes to be a telephone# in some HTML (what you see above).  In my case, I do not need or want phone number detection.  So I stuck

`<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no" />`

in the master page header.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using text();

```
var partnerId = $('.partnerId').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you only want the number:

```
$('.partnerId').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something tells me that you will not be able to overcome this for particular sub tree in the DOM. For global solution see P.Brian.Mackey's answer.
Using `.text()` is the most reliable and effective option I think.

In fact on IE or FF you may get the same if you have for example Skype plugin installed and the number looks like a phone number.